# Is there a way of computing a prominence score based on the prevalence of features in an image?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, reference-request, statistical-ai

Is there any previous work on computing some sort of prominence score based on the prevalence of features in an image?

For example, let's say I am classifying images based on whether or not they have dogs in them. Is there a way to compute how prominent that feature is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saliency is typically discussed more in object detection or scene understanding than prominence.  There are lots of papers on saliency models.  ["What do different evaluation metrics tell us about saliency models?"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03605) is a good paper on various metrics on saliency models.  It covers the following metrics:

1. Similarity or histogram intersection (SIM)
2. Pearson's Correlation Coefficient (CC)
3. Normalized Scanpath Saliency (NSS)
4. Area Under ROC Curve (AUC)
5. Information Gain (IG)
6. Kullback-Leibler divergence (KL)
7. Earth Mover's Distance (EMD)

Some other papers you may find interesting:

1. [Saliency, attention, and visual search: An information
   theoretic approach](http://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~bruce/AIM2009.pdf)
2. [Towards Instance Segmentation with Object Priority:
   Prominent Object Detection and Recognition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.07402)